# Spinner or progress bar while images are loaded, not blocking UI

Tags: android

I have an async task that loads images. 
How could i display a spinner just inside of the gallery where the images will be loaded to display that some work is being done? Or progress bar?
But i want to be able to do this without blocking up the whole UI.

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More common pattern is to put the indicator into activity title bar to show that some background work is in progress.

To do that you should request window feature

```
requestFeature(FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

and later use

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true|false)
```

to show/hide the progress

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 it will show progress indicator in the top-right corner of the title. I googled this link http://androidyou.blogspot.com/2010/07/android-showing-indeterminate-progress.html it has a screenshot..

Comment: It worked on android honeycomb but not on my gingerbread devices?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 you can change the title of the activity if you want, but I don't think there is a way to attach a message to the indicator

Comment: Its nice to keep the spinner in the title across all activities as it makes it easy for the user to see that there is something going on without having to look different places or even ending up having multiple spinners on screen at once.

Answer (score 5):

You can inflate custom layout in `getView()` method in your ImageAdapter (check example on official Google website http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) e.g.:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String[] mUrls = {
        "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/fap/image/0011/arcadenov9_trace.jpg",
        "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/fap/image/0011/earthlights_dmsp_big.jpx",
        "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/fap/image/0011/earthlights2_dmsp_big.jpx"
    }
    private boolean[] flags = new boolean[3]; // 3 images example
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
        if (!flags[position]) {
            image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idImage);
            progressBar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idProgressBar);
            new DownloadTask(image, progressBar, mUrls[position]).execute();
            flags[position]=true;
        }
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Where `gallery_item.xml` looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/idProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In `getView()` method you can pass ProgressBar and ImageView instances to `DownloadTask` (class that extends `AsyncTask`) e.g.

```
new DownloadTask(image, progressBar, mUrls[position]).execute();
```

In `doInBackground()` you should download (and/or somehow cache/persist) image (URL is in mUrls[position]) and in `onPostExecute()` (that is run in UI thread) you should:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide progress
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // set image
```

As a show case you can use one Activity only with main.xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/idGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put a `ProgressBar` under the Gallery in your layout XML which can either just contain a spinner (with bar style `Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Invers`e or `Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse`) You can set it to always spinning by setting the xml attribute `android:indeterminateOnly="true"`.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

You can have an Async Task that loads your images into your gallery (or however you are doing it), and when the Async Task is done you can set the visibility of the ProgressBar to View.Gone.

EDIT: Here's some code example for the xml

```
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
        <Gallery XML here>
        <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/progress"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallInverse"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:indeterminateOnly="true" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not too sure how your gallery loads your images, but basically you need a mechanism to tell you when the images finish loading (generally I say you wouldn't need a spinner as images should seem to load almost instantly, but maybe you are loading something that requires a lot of time). When your images finish loading just call `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. If you want a TextView saying loading or something feel free to put it in the XML as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example like the person below. and you will get the correct answer. Sorry im a little new to this

Comment: I gave you an example of the xml. I'm not going to go into detail for the async task or your loading mechanism because I don't know anything about your app.

Comment: Thats cool i know how to handle the code for the asyncTask. Just needed a idea of what you were saying

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
private void showProgrssBar(){
pLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
final StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();
final Thread progressThread=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){


            while(CreateVideoService.processingFrame>1) {
                 inc=100-((CreateVideoService.processingFrame*100)/(CreateVideoService.numberofRecordedFrames));
                 if(s.length()>0)
                 s.delete(0, s.length());
                 s.append("Processing... ").append(inc).append("%");
                 progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        progressBar.setProgress(inc);
                        textProgrs.setText(s); 
                    }
                });
                 //progressBar.setProgress(100-inc);
                 try {
                     // Sleep for 5 seconds
                     Thread.sleep(200);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     //Log.d("TAG", "sleep failure");
                 }
            }
            layoutHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    pLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

    }
};
progressThread.start();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a ProgressDialog in onPreExecute method of your AsyncTask

```
    private String message;    
    private ProgressDialog dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityClass.this);

         protected void onPreExecute()
         {

            message="Loading images.\n Please wait...";
             dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivityClass.this, "", 
                     message, true);

         }
```

And cancel the dialog in onPostExecute() method

Comment: But wouldnt this block up my whole UI? Thats what i dont want

Comment: I only want it to display in the gallery where the images will be\

Comment: what do you mean by blocking whole UI?

Comment: Meaning i have buttons on the same scree...I dont want the dialog to stop the user from interacting with the activty as a whole. But i just want to display something letting the user know work is being done

Comment: I think you can--PUt a textView in the screen on a position where you want to show something happening initially hidden.Show it when background works starting.And hide again after finishing the background work.For showing use onPreExecute and to hide use onPostExectue.You can't access UI from doInBackground

Comment: Images are loading..or any other message you want

Comment: Oh i could have like images loading..... or something.. i see..Or i could create some time of loading in graphic and use that. What do you think? as a image view..Show it in pre execute and then hide it in on postExecute. But how would this go in fron of the gallery or over top of it? Would that affect the gallery even though the imageview would be invisible?

Comment: You have to modify your gallery layout for the message widget.Its better using progress bar.If you know how manage you are loading you can show the exact progress

Comment: so how would i go about using the progress without blocking up the whole ui?

Comment: yes,if you use progress bar it is a widget like button,edittext,imageview.it will be just showing the progress without blocking the UI

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html. How to use progress bar

Comment: hmmm i see..So How will i actually use this in XML though? How will i specifiy that the progress dialog only should be over top of the gallery not smack in the center of the GUI?

Comment: You have to give it some place in the GUI.Because if you show bar in a dialog parent will be disabled